How to resolve Error migrating WSL disk on Docker desktop windows 11 WSL 2 backend?
I am trying to change Disk image location in Docker Desktop v4.31.1 on my windows machine following this path:
"Docker Desktop > Settings > Resources > Advanced > Disk image location"
And I am selecting D:\Docker directory using Browse Button as new destination. when I click Apply & restart button, it will show following error:
Error migrating WSL disk
An error occurred while migrating the Docker Desktop WSL data disk to its new location:

moving disk file: rename C:\Users\Reza\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\disk\docker_data.vhdx D:\Docker\DockerDesktopWSL\disk\docker_data.vhdx: The system canot move the file to a different disk drive.

Disk image location will be reverted to its original setting.


Result of wsl -l -v:
  NAME              STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop    Running         2

Windows info:
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 23H2
OS build    22631.3737

Docker info:
Client:
 Version:    26.1.4
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.14.1-desktop.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-buildx.exe
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.27.1-desktop.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-compose.exe
  debug: Get a shell into any image or container (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  0.0.32
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-debug.exe
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.2
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-dev.exe
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.24
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-extension.exe
  feedback: Provide feedback, right in your terminal! (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.0.5
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-feedback.exe
  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.2.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-init.exe
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-sbom.exe
  scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v1.9.3
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-scout.exe

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 26.1.4
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d2d58213f83a351ca8f528a95fbd145f5654e957
 runc version: v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
 Kernel Version: 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 3.818GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: cce2006d-d665-4857-80af-dbfb1eda2369
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Labels:
  com.docker.desktop.address=npipe://\\.\pipe\docker_cli
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_bps_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.read_iops_device support
WARNING: No blkio throttle.write_iops_device support
WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile

I tried with admin privelages also and got same error.
I checked C:\Users\Reza\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\disk\docker_data.vhdx and it is existen.
My D drive has enough free space and it's file system is NTFS and Compress this drive to save disk space is not checked/activated.
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Exact same problem here, with same versions of everything

I seems it was an issue long time ago https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13269 and now its back somehow https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13345

this is a bug in that version. It is now solved in docker desktop v4.32.0

This is a known issue in Docker Desktop v4.31.1. This issue has been fixed in Docker Desktop v4.32.0. You can update the Docker Desktop to v4.32.0 by

"Docker Desktop > Settings > Software Updates > Check for updates"

Finally, restart your windows.

Actually it's a problem in v4.34 as well. I selected a new location, Docker started migrating and right after the app crashed and could not be started again. There are 2x path properties in settings.json and one was not updated correctly.

According to this issue comment a possible workaround is:

quit docker desktop
edit %APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json, change the location to what ever you want
start docker desktop

I haven't tried yet, posting for reference and I will update after I try.
It's good to know there's an open issue...
